# iad banner every time by viewvillappear

Tags: swift

I would like to show an ad banner every time if the viewcontroller will be appear. I have this code for this:

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class LMTableViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    var adView: ADBannerView?

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        self.view.addSubview(adView!)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        adView!.removeFromSuperview()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // iAd
        self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Manual
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the ad will not be shown every time.
It will be shown very randomly.
Can everybody tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit


import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var adBannerView: ADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() 


{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.adBannerView.delegate = self
    self.adBannerView.hidden = true


}



func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {


}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    self.adBannerView.hidden = false

}



func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {


}
}
```

Paste the above code in your project. Hope this helps.

Best of luck,

Suprem

Comment: sry, i would like to show an full screen adbanner. your code should only show a small banner